# Some questions about the temporal relationship about gradle and gradlew

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm learning gradle and some questions bother me

When I want to use gradle, I'd better use gradlew. But when I want to use gradlew, I need a installed gradle. So is that a story about chicken and egg?

Should be gradle-wrapper.jar uploaded to git repository? Some docs say git should track it, but it seems not good to track a binary file with git.

Answer (score 1):

Using `./gradlew` you are using a **gradle wrapper**. The wrapper is part of a project and it is able to download and install a specific version of gradle.

The Gradle Wrapper consists of a few files in your project directory:

- `gradlew`: The shell script Unix users can run to execute Gradle tasks
- `gradlew.bat` The bat script Windows users can run to execute Gradle tasks
- `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` The wrapper’s executable JAR; this is where the wrapper code resides
- `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` A properties file for configuring the wrapper

Using the wrapper guarantees that every developer on your team in a specified project is using the **same version** of Gradle and that they can run Gradle builds.
**You should make sure all these are committed to version control**

You can easily change the version of gradle used in the project just changing the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file with the `distributionUrl` properties. For example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip
```

You can find more info about the [wrapper here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

Using `./gradle` you need to download and install **manually** the gradle version before.
It means that every developer in a team can use different version on the same project.